# Problems with parametric types

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia 1.5.2 on Win10

version 1: This one compiles. It actually works if all values of the Dict are of type 'V'. But that is not exactly what I want.

```
struct MyData{K,V} 
    data::AbstractVector{<:AbstractDict{<:K,V}}
end
```

version 2: This is what I actually want, but the compiler throws an `UndefVarError: V not defined` exception. The only different is `{<:K,V}` vs `{<:K,<:V}`

```
struct MyData{K,V} 
    data::AbstractVector{<:AbstractDict{<:K,<:V}}
end
```

Update: How to reproduce

```
julia> struct MyStruct{K,V}
           data::AbstractVector{<:AbstractDict{<:K,<:V}}
           end

julia> ar = [Dict{String,Any}("a" => 1)]
1-element Array{Dict{String,Any},1}:
 Dict("a" => 1)

julia> MyStruct(ar)
ERROR: UndefVarError: V not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] MyStruct(::Array{Dict{String,Any},1}) at .\REPL[1]:2
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[3]:1
```

Any idea why that is and how to fix it?

thanks for your help

Comment: They both work for me. Can you show the error that is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be:

```
struct MyStructNew{K,V}
    data::AbstractVector{<:AbstractDict{K,V}}
end
```

That is is your parametric types need to be concrete:

Here is the test:

```
julia> MyStructNew(ar)
MyStructNew{String,Any}(Dict{String,Any}[Dict("a" => 1)])

julia> MyStructNew([Dict{Number, AbstractString}(3=>"a")])
MyStructNew{Number,AbstractString}(Dict{Number,AbstractString}[Dict(3 => "a")])
```

If you actually want the types of `K` and `V` to be abstract you can use your original `struct` but need to provide those types so Julia knows how to construct your object:

```
julia> struct MyStruct{K,V}
           data::AbstractVector{<:AbstractDict{<:K,<:V}}
       end

julia> MyStruct{AbstractString,Any}(ar)
MyStruct{AbstractString,Any}(Dict{String,Any}[Dict("a" => 1)])
```

Comment: This only works if the AbstractDict has K keys and V values. It doesn't work for keys <: K or values <: V.

Comment: This one works, because it is explicit https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#Parametric-Constructors.  Any suggestion why the implicit version doesn't work?

Comment: what type do you expect the compiler to use for `K` and `V` in the implicit version?

Comment: The best option is my first answer combined with abstract types in `Dict` constructor. Try ` MyStructNew([Dict{Number, AbstractString}(3=>"a")])`